# Swift - The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfilemanager

I'm saving to `FileManager.default.documentDirectory` the **url** as **string** for some video I select from **Library**. I am able to load and use them with no problem, but if I run the app again, when I load the array of url, I can't use them as I get this error:

> The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

of this one

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

I have tried all solutions I could find googling the errors, but nothing solve it.
Any help will be much appreciated.

I'm developing for iOS. Xcode Version 11.3.1

Comment: You shouldn't save the whole file path. It will change every time you run the app. You can save its name and reconstruct your URL before loading it.

Comment: Please report the complete error message here. Hope reported error message contains complete path of the URL

Comment: @LeoDabus - you're right, post your answer to validate.

Comment: It is about the code. If you show what you’re doing, then we can see what the problem is with it. Otherwise we’re just guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem there is that the file path will change every time you run the app. You shouldn't save the whole file path. You can save its name and reconstruct your URL before loading it.